# sql insert query with subquery input and additional parameter

Tags: sql

insert into sycle(name,password) values(select name from name_table,'name');

i am having problem in inserting additional value with the parameter received from the select subquery.

it can be done in two query, but i want to kn ow if it can be done in a single query.

Comment: Where is 'password' coming from?

Answer (score 2):

```
insert into sycle(name,password)
select name, password from name_table
```

or if password is a variable:

```
insert into sycle(name,password)
select name, @password from name_table
```

if password is 'name' then:

```
insert into sycle(name,password)
select name, 'name' from name_table
```

Comment: no i want to hardcode a value 'name' as password....its not coming from table....

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
  INSERT INTO sycle(name,password) VALUES (SELECT name, 'name' FROM name_table);
```

although this will take only single name from name_table.  If you want to get a whole bunch of values do:

```
  INSERT INTO sycle(name,password) SELECT name, 'name' FROM name_table;
```

Comment: what is your rdbms? Are you using mysql or sql server?

Answer (score 1):

This is what you're looking for:

```
INSERT INTO sycle
(
   name
   ,password
)
SELECT  name
        ,NULL -- password
FROM    name_table
```

Comment: its not working      after using -- all the remaining query is commented

Comment: Yes, the double dash is a comment. Make sure there is a new line after the word password or just remove `-- password` altogether.

Answer (score 0):

give this a try

insert into sycle select name,'name' from name_table

Comment: This will not work if you there are more than two columns in scycle, or if the columns are not in the desired order.

Comment: Very true but we don't really have access to the structures and I was just pointing him in the proper direction - should have made the code a bit more defensive however. You're right.